# Añadir script en systemd

Tags: linux

Necesito evitar que se haga un *start* de un script (systemctl start mysql) añadiendo otro script previo en bash. En caso de que este script falle, no se ejecutaria el *start* y apareceria un mensaje por pantalla

Como ejemplo:

```
ExecStartPre=/script/control.sh
ExecStartPre=/usr/mysql-10/bin/mysql-10-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/usr/mysql-10/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA}
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
```

Es posible con la siguiente linea:

```
ExecStartPre=/script/control.sh
```

y con el contenido siguiente:

```
cat /script/control.sh
exit 0
```

Evitar que se arranque finalmente el proceso?

Gracias

Comment: Lectura obligatoria mi estimado/a : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: perdón! olvidé poner como bien indicas el contenido.

Comment: @GuifIf ¿te valió la respuesta que te dí? ¿Necesitas más información?

Answer (score 0):

Te diría que sí, que es correcto.

De todas formas tienes toda la información necesaria aquí:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=

Creo que te puede ayudar.

Aún así, tendrías que crear el fichero `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service` si editas el propio fichero de `systemd` (`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysqld.service`) una actualización de MySQL o del servidor se lo podría cargar.

Es mejor crear tu propio fichero que modificar el de por defecto.